# Загрузка Изображений

Tags: ajax, javascript, php, mysql

Помогите дописать скрип: есть аjax форма для выбора и загрузки с предпросмотром изображений, как сделать так, что-бы можно было огранить количество выбранный изображений?

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
//Обработчики событий интрфейса
//Удаление выбранного фото
  $(".delpreview").live("click", function(){
  $(this).parent().remove();
});

//Upload
$(function(){ 
  var btnUpload=$('#upload');
  var status=$('#status');
  new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
    action: 'upload-file.php',
    name: 'uploadfile',
    onSubmit: function(file, ext){
      if (! (ext && /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$/.test(ext))){ 
        status.html('<div class="act_error" style="margin-top: -25px;">Поддерживаемые на Сайте Форматы<br/>Изображений: JPG, PNG или GIF</div>');
      return false;
      }
      status.html('<center><div id="load"></div></center>');
    },
    onComplete: function(file, response){
      status.text('');
      if(response==="success"){   
        $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').html('<center><a class="zoom" href="uploads/'+file+'" "><img src="uploads/'+file+'" alt="" /></a></center><input type="hidden" name="person['+file+'][images]" value="uploads/'+file+'" /><span class="delpreview"></span>').addClass('success');
        $().appendTo(li);
      }else {
        $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').text('Файл не загружен: (Проверьте Формат: IMG) ' + file).addClass('act_error');
      } 
    } 
  });
});
</script>
<!--ZOOM-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="zoom/zoom.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="zoom/zoom.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrap" >
    <h1>Загрузка изображений с Предосмотром (Ajax, jQuery, PHP)</h1>
      <div id="upload">Выбрать файл</div>
      <form action="post.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <span id="status" ></span>
        <form action="post.php" method="POST">
          <ul id="files"></ul>
        </form>
      </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: дядя, код отформатируйте как следует.

Comment: как сделать, чтобы пользователь мог загрузить только 5 изображений за раз! Как это сделать?

Comment: <input type="file" name="files" multiple />, а вкоде делать проверку, если массив files содержит больше пяти элементов - выдавать ошибку и не продолжать загрузку

Comment: как это реализовать на моем примере, помогите, очень надо?